# How to use Connection.CommandTimeout on Access-ADP?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to increase the timeout of a query using Access ADP connected to SQL Server 2008.

I'm trying this command:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.CommandTimeout = 0
```

And then debugging and printing this:

```
print CurrentProject.Connection.CommandTimeout
```

All I get is `30`. Somehow it doesn't change to `0`.

Does anyone have experience changing the timeout value using Access-ADP project? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentProject.Connection` is used for obtaining a new ADO connection to the database. You can make changes to it, but it's only for this newly created connection, and if you're not referring to it (e.g. `Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection`), the new connection immediately gets destroyed after you've changed the setting.

You can set timeouts in many places. You can set timeouts for the entire application under access options -> client settings -> advanced.

ADPs are no longer supported since 2013. I don't have a test setup to test the specifics, but you should be able to set timeouts per object that override application-wide timeouts. Also, when executing queries through VBA, you can specify timeouts by modifying the queries connection. For example, you can change the timeout on an ADO recordset by using `Recordset.Connection.CommandTimeout = 0`

Answer (score 0):

options -> advanced didn't work. I changed to 0 but during execution it keeps the default timeout of 30.

However, since you mentioned to create a new connection, this worked for me:

```
 Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
 Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
 conn.CommandTimeout = 0
 Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
 rst.Open query, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Thanks for your help.